# Record TCP traffic for replication as a load test

Tags: load, load-testing

I would like to know if there is a way to record web traffic in such a way that I can use it to 'replay' the same load over and over for optimization testing under a known live load.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [tcpcopy](https://github.com/wangbin579/tcpcopy) is the tool that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) it's a powerful network diagnostic tool. But this tool has no build in function to replay the traffic.

IHMO it makes no sense to simply rebuild all requests depending on your technology you could destroy everything. So be careful with modification data. It could make nonsense responses and throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this - but this approach is really only valid for static content. And since the performance of a system serving static content is generally well known and scales well, there is little reason to do load testing this way.  IIRC, there was a load testing product sold as a piece of hardware that did this many years ago. I haven't run across them in years, though.

The reason that only static sites can be tested this way is that in the more typical, interactive site, a single session CAN NOT be replayed exactly as it was recorded. Many bits of the HTTP messages change for each iteration by each user. For example: cookies, content expiration and last-modified headers and other values in URL query parameters, form fields and AJAX requests that are necessary for the application to manage session state among the many concurrent users.

Incidentally, configuring all of these fields to send the correct values is the biggest challenge for load testing tools that use HTTP capture and replay (which is almost all of them). Doing it for a single session can be hard. Doing it for a massive capture of network traffic from many users raises the bar a good deal.

Answer (score 0):

Both Jmeter and the Grinder have a recording proxy that allows for HTTP recordings which can be played back. Although you may need to change the requests to parse out any required dynamic data from previous requests. That said record/playback is a good staring point for HTTP traffic construction. Also the Grinder has a TCP recording proxy, as per your question, (that has a HTTP option) so you can really get detailed traffic. - http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/tcpproxy.html

Comment: Great info. I'll definitely look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning this as another option since it hasn't been listed here yet:
https://github.com/buger/gor

Gor is built to do specifically what you're asking for HTTP, and the "pro" version will handle HTTPS. Gor is built in Go, and has many advanced features: https://gortool.com/

It is open source, with a "pro" version available with some additional features.